# how to pass a varible from an option from to my Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone show me how to gather the value select on.change of the dropdown box and then use that value as a varible in my controller. 
for some reason the $ColorPicked varible will not revolve in the $scope.base = response.data.type.$ColorPicked; BUT if i just remove the $ColorPicked and type in Red it works no problem.

I am still very new to Angular and JS for that matter so please excuse my stupidity. I have Googled and Googled for a clear cut answer and I got nothing.

```
INDEX.HTML
<h3>Color:</h3>
<select class="formBoxes" id="ColorPicked">
<option value="Red">Redd</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
</select>

SCRIPT.JS
$ColorPicked = "Red";

var app = angular.module("computer",['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
    when('/main',{
       templateUrl: 'archetype.html',
      controller:'MainCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({redirectTo:'/main'})
}])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('archetype.json').then(function(response){

    $scope.base = response.data.type.$ColorPicked;

    ;
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things,

(i)You need to have a $scope variable defined for the `ColorPicked` inorder to provide the default selection.

(ii)You need to have ng-model which gets bind to the variable. Pass the selected Color to the function using the [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive

**HTML:**

```
 <select ng-model="ColorPicked" ng-change="setItem(ColorPicked)">
      <option>Red</option>
      <option>Blue</option>
      <option>Green</option>    
  </select>
```

**Controller:**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.ColorPicked = "Red";    
    $scope.setItem = function(opt) {
    $scope.base =opt;
  }
}
```

[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/d1enb3t2/3/)

[`Working Demo for your requirement`](https://plnkr.co/edit/uSYOmi3MY1dXa4AqRq5R?p=preview)

Comment: IDK who downvoted you but I cant get either of these to work.

Again, I am new to this and I need a clear way to get the value of the drop down and then use that value in $scope.base = response.data.type.$ColorPicked;

Comment: @SamBush Just call this inside the ng-change function,  $scope.base =opt;

Comment: I think thats my problems. Based on my code provided above in the question, I dont really know where this even goes.

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.ColorPicked = "Red";    
    $scope.setItem = function(opt) {
    $scope.base =opt;
  }
}

Comment: 1 sec Ill set up a plunkr

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/lJDOP830iiEEbGmhohSc?p=preview

Thank You again for all of your help.

Comment: @SamBush check here https://plnkr.co/edit/uSYOmi3MY1dXa4AqRq5R?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `ng-model` to bind the selected value to the controller's property.  If you want to initialize the select input to a value on the model, then you need to use `ng-options`

```
<select ng-model="selectedColor"
        ng-options="opt.value as opt.label for opt in opts">
</select>
```

and in your controller you would have the following on your scope:

```
$scope.opts = [
    { value:'red', label:'Red' },
    { value:'blue', label:'Blue' },
    { value:'green', label:'Green' },
]

$http.get(...).then( function( response ){ 
    $scope.selectedColor = response.data.type.$colorPicked;
})
```